# Localization in Android App For Dynamic Data from Server

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

In my application, user can select his native language so that can easily read the content of application. I know how to write if the content is static, but my requirement the content should be  come from server. So how can I do this? Please give me the approach? Whether it can be done from my client (by using android code) side? or we need to write the code from server (web services) side? Please help me

Comment: Use UTF-8 to communicate with the server and read the same in android. It should render the text properly. Read this blog http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html. There is support for indian languages on android in case you are looking for the same

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan...Could you please give me the more details about UTF-8

Comment: You can Google and find out more. The blog gives a brief idea of how things work with utf8 on java

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you should handle this from Server

Comment: Thanks for quick replay..sadegh..I am using Microsoft Azure Mobile services using .NET framework.So,how can I do this??any Idea??

Comment: you can send the language of user which has set on device as a parameter to your server and server respond the localized text